# asp.net copy website tool copied to remote server but not able to open the web page on remote server

Tags: asp.net

I am totally new to ASP.NET. I might be asking so silly question. I have already created a web page and using copy website tool I have copied each and every file and folder to the remote server. Now, how to open a web page on the remote server? I tried opening by double clicking on the default.aspx but it just shows the header of the page and something like the following:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

Do I need to copy it to inetpub rootfoleder or any where?
Do I need to have visual studio installed on the remote server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394698%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) article will explain how to publish a website or web application via Visual Studio. That article is for Visual Studio 2012 but the same articles exist for other versions.

In short you need the following

- ASP.NET Website or Web Application created in Visual Studio.
- Internet Information Services (IIS) installed and configured on remote server.

[Here](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-iis-7) is an article that explains how to install IIS 7. The same types of article exist for other versions of IIS in case you are running a newer or older operating system than 2008.

FYI - You do not need Visual Studio installed on the remote server.

If you need help finding more detailed information, reply back with more info regarding the version of Visual Studio you are using and the operating system on the remote server.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Working all because of you. By the way I am using Visual Studio 2013 and operating system on the remote server is windows server 2012. The only thing I am confused about is trust level in web.config file. upon adding <trust level="Medium" /> throws an error because the web page is accessing company's active directory so, had to get rid of it. No clue when to add trust level.